# Google App Engine displays nothing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to take data from user and store it in database but even my form isn't displaying on chrome. I am new to google app engine please help. Following is my complete code

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Dealer(db.Model):
   dealer_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
   dealer_phone = db.StringProperty(required = True)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("""
        <form action="store_dealer" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="dealer_name">
            <input type="text" name="dealer_phone">
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    """)

class StoreDealer(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        dealer_name=self.request.get('dealer_name')
        dealer_phone=self.request.get('dealer_phone')
        if dealer_name && dealer_phone:
            dealer = Dealer(dealer_name = dealer_name, dealer_phone =     dealer_phone)
            dealer.put()
            self.redirect('/')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/store_dealer',StoreDealer)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `&&` is `and` in Python.

So your code should be like this.

```
class StoreDealer(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        ..........
        if dealer_name and dealer_phone:
            ...........
```

To view the errors on Google App Engine, Please check its log console.